# Can I make Python throw exception when equal comparing different data types?

Tags: python, exception, types, error-handling

Say I want to compare 2 variables with different data types: string and int. I have tested it both in Python 2.7.3 and Python 3.2.3 and neither throws exception. The result of comparison is `False`. Can I configure or run Python with different options to throw exception in this case?

```
ks@ks-P35-DS3P:~$ python2
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a="123"
>>> b=123
>>> a==b
False
>>> 
ks@ks-P35-DS3P:~$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 12 2012, 19:08:59) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a="123"
>>> b=123
>>> a==b
False
>>> 
ks@ks-P35-DS3P:~$
```

Comment: Are you wanting to overload `__eq__` for all objects?

Comment: What is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid: I want to protect myself from accident comparing of unrelated types and to know about it as early as possible.

Comment: "Unrelated" types is different from "different" types. You might want to clarify what you mean. Do you want an exception when you compare a unicode with a str, for example? What about a float and an int? I think adding an exception like this is very subtle and will probably not do what you want.

Comment: @Jesse Rusak: I mean that these variables are equal in some sense and they will do be equal if convert `a` to int explicitly. But actually they are not equal because of different data types.

Comment: The best way to avoid such accidents is to write unittests

Comment: @gnibbler: Yes, but I wanted it to be a bit self tested.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't. The items are just not equal, there is no error there.

Generally speaking, it is *unpythonic* to force your code to only accept specific types. What if you wanted to create a subclass of the `int`, and have it work everywhere an `int` works? The Python boolean type is a subclass of `int`, for example (`True` == 1, `False` == 0).

If you have to have an exception, you can do one of two things:

1. Test for equality on their types and raise an exception yourself:

   ```
   if not isinstance(a, type(b)) and not isinstance(b, type(a)):
       raise TypeError('Not the same type')
   if a == b:
       # ...
   ```

   This example allows for either a or b to be a subclass of the other type, you'd need to narrow that down as needed (`type(a) is type(b)` to be super strict).
2. Try to *order* the types:

   ```
   if not a < b and not a > b:
       # ...
   ```

   In Python 3, this throws an exception when comparing numerical types with sequence types (such as strings). The comparisons succeed in Python 2.

   Python 3 demo:

   ```
   >>> a, b = 1, '1'
   >>> not a < b and not a > b
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
   >>> a, b = 1, 1
   >>> not a < b and not a > b
   True
   ```

Comment: You could mention a notable subtype of int, boolean. (+1 though, great answer.)

Comment: Same comment here; your isinstance check is not symmetric, which will make the equality check also not symmetric, which is very weird.

Comment: @JesseRusak That would be easy to fix though.  Just perform both directions of checking.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Yes, but if you check both directions, do you throw an exception if either fails (i.e. both types must be identical) or if both fail (i.e. you also permit one type must be a subtype of the other)? This is a critical point about the nature of this check.

Comment: Good point.  That's something only the OP could answer for us, as he has specific requirements, I'm sure.

Comment: Strange that Python3 throws exception in case of `<` comparison but not in case of `==`

Comment: @ks1322: Not at all. You cannot *order* different types (should 1 come before `foobar` or after?) but you *can* determine that they are not equal.

Comment: But there are many cases where classes are comparable but not orderable, right? Option 2 seems a little weird to me. Overall, I for one _love_ the fact that Python has essentially polymorphism built in. For example, you can easily and without much ceremonial make a Bloom filter that implements equality comparison with any `set`, even though its members cannot be enumerated.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to accomplish it that wouldn't be too ugly to use routinely. This is one case where the Python programmer has to be careful about datatypes without help from the language.

Just be thankful you're not using a language where datatypes get silently coerced between string and int.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function to do so:

```
def isEqual(a, b):
    if not isinstance(a, type(b)): raise TypeError('a and b must be of same type')
    return a == b # only executed if an error is not raised
```

Comment: That's not symmetric right now: `isEqual(fooInstance, fooSubclassInstance)` would throw an exception, but `isEqual(fooSubclassInstance, fooInstance)` wouldn't.