# Python: Raise error when comparing objects of different type for equality

Tags: python

As far as I understand, in Python, comparing the instances of two different classes for equality, does:

- evaluate the `__eq__` method of the first instance and return the result
- Except if the result is `NotImplemented`, then evaluate the `__eq__` method of the second instance and return the result
- Except if the result is `NotImplemented`, then compare for object identity and return the result (which is False)

I encountered multiple times situations where a raised Exception would have helped me to spot a bug in my code. Martijn Pieters has sketched in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15451530/1217284) a way to do that, but also mentioned that it's unpythonic.

Besides being unpythonic, are there actual problems arising from this approach?

Comment: Are you using a linter? If so, perhaps you can configure it to warn when objects of different types are compared?

Comment: Option 1. of [the post you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15451530/758174) is the best one IMHO, and you should use it only if you really need to. I just added a [comment there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451472/can-i-make-python-throw-exception-when-equal-comparing-different-data-types/15451530#comment124698160_15451530) to highlight the fact that it is indeed very desirable to have polymorphism essentially built in Python.

Comment: @md2perpe You are right, a static type checker would probably do the trick as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it is, of course, "unpythonic" because Python encourages duck typing alongside strict subtyping. But I personally prefer strictly typed interfaces, so I throw `TypeError`s. Never had any issues, but I can't difinitively say that you will never have any.

Theoretically, I can imagine it being a problem if you find yourself in need to use a mixed-type container like `list[Optional[YourType]]` and then compare its elements, maybe indirectly, like in constructing `set(your_mixed_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

It would cause problems for dictionaries with mixed keys that have the same hash. Dictionaries allow several keys to have the same hash, and then do an equality check to distinguish keys. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9022835/1217284

The following script demonstrates this, it fails when the class `Misbehaving1` is used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Behaving1:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __hash__(self):
        return 7

class Behaving2:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __hash__(self):
        return 7
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not (isinstance(other, type(self)) or isinstance(self, type(other))):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.value == other.value


class MisBehaving1:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __hash__(self):
        return 7
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not (isinstance(other, type(self)) or isinstance(self, type(other))):
            raise TypeError(f"Cannot compare {self} of type {type(self)} with {other} of type {type(other)}")
        return self.value == other.value


d = {Behaving1(5): 'hello', Behaving2(4): 'world'}
print(d)

dd = {Behaving1(5): 'hello', MisBehaving1(4): 'world'}
print(dd)
```